# SQL Server 2019 in Docker: You can accept the EULA by specifying the --accept-eula command line option

Tags: sql-server, docker

Command

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=123456a@' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

docker logs -f 1b2ce04432883df593535157999ae3d2996620155b71e0e1d9fd25e8b2e60628
```

Document: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

[image]

[image]

[image]

I see my error

```
SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.

This container is running as user mssql.

To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.

The SQL Server End-User License Agreement (EULA) must be accepted before SQL

Server can start. The license terms for this product can be downloaded from

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746388.


You can accept the EULA by specifying the --accept-eula command line option,

setting the ACCEPT_EULA environment variable, or using the mssql-conf tool.

SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.

This container is running as user mssql.

To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.

The SQL Server End-User License Agreement (EULA) must be accepted before SQL

Server can start. The license terms for this product can be downloaded from

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746388.


You can accept the EULA by specifying the --accept-eula command line option,

setting the ACCEPT_EULA environment variable, or using the mssql-conf tool.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? [Connect from outside the container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-powershell#connectexternal). Unless you have port forwarding enabled, you won't be able to connect with the IP `127.0.0.1`. Considering you don't mention that, I assume you do not.

Comment: It not running, let's tell me how to make SQL server run first.

Comment: Yes, you need to accept the aggreement first

Comment: Please guide me how to accept agrrement. step by step

Comment: That, too, is all in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-powershell#pullandrun2019) I linked to. You need to include `-e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"` in your `run` command.

Comment: As you seen, in my command also have this part `-e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y'` https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/95756591-29dcd000-0cd0-11eb-8e3f-cd3468505702.png

Comment: So have you followed the rest of the instructions in the error mesasge, which tells you other methods (as you have posted an [image of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRaI5.png), I can't copy the relevant bit).

Comment: `You can accept the EULA by specifying the --accept-eula command line option,

setting the ACCEPT_EULA environment variable, or using the mssql-conf tool.` How to use command line? How to start `mssql-conf`?

Comment: in the Container's command line.

Comment: but it not run, I cannot use container's command line.

Comment: Can you tell us which operating system you’re running on? That may affect the command line.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is an error in reference document (at https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server ).

[image]

Fix it

Use `" "` , not `' '`

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=123456a@" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Another reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash#pullandrun2019

See more at https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/199#issuecomment-346092077

Comment: OMG answer is to use DOUBLE QUOTES!!!! Thanks for posing your solution. It was such simple mistake, I was almost pulling my hair trying to fix this.

Comment: I have no trouble using single quotes: `sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Test@321' -p 1433:1433 -d --name sql-server microsoft/mssql-server-linux`. However my host in on Linux, so the issue may have something to do with the host.

Comment: @thanks works on mac appleSilicon chip

Comment: Not related directly to question and answer. Update: Latest version, it works: `docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=123456a@" -e "MSSQL_PID=Evaluation" -p 1433:1433 --name sqlpreview --hostname sqlpreview -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-preview-ubuntu-22.04
`

Comment: Is not error in documentation. Say «Start a mssql-server... IMPORTANT NOTE: If you are using PowerShell on Windows to run these commands use double quotes instead of single quotes.»